# How exactly do I fix my eclipse and not the bug?

Tags: eclipse

I have [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389491) in my eclipse which causes the screen to go black when moving unfocused tab around, it's really annoying and I'm trying to figure out how do I apply the fix mentioned in the above link. I tried to understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368941/how-to-apply-an-existing-patch-to-your-eclipse-ide) and I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066098/apply-patch-to-fix-bug-in-eclipse) but these didn't help, and trying to google for it brings up either info about how to fix the bugs themselves, or how to create patches.

I just want to fix my eclipse, the bug has been already fixed and I want to apply that fix to my eclipse, any thorough and detailed answers are welcome,

thanks

Comment: Windows 7 professional 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade your Eclipse installation to 4.3. The bug has been fixed in that version and that version was released in June 2013.